# How can we calculate mean?

Tags: mean, c#

In the [***AForge.net***](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/f492924fd60fc8cdf8f783733bbb5c120ce5c92a/Sources/Math/Statistics.cs#L47) the mean value of a vector is calculated as follows:

```
    public static double Mean( int[] values )
    {
        int     hits;
        double  total = 0;
        double  mean = 0;

        // for all values
        for ( int i = 0, n = values.Length; i < n; i++ )
        {
            hits = values[i];
            // accumulate mean
            mean += (double) i * hits;
            // accumalate total
            total += hits;
        }
        return ( total == 0 ) ? 0 : mean / total;
    }
```

I couldn't understand this.

As far as I know mean is the value where sum is divided by the count of numbers.

Can anyone explain this to me?

What does it mean by **`hits`** here?

Also, **do we calculate mean of real numbers  in the same way?**

Comment: Did you read the comments immediately above the line you linked to?

Comment: @Kodiologist, Yes. I couldn't understand .

Comment: Hint: the code reveals that the indexes `i` to the `values` vector range from $0$ through $n$, that these *indexes* represent the values, and that `values[i]` is the *count* of the value `i` in the dataset.  Your other questions (about `hits` and casting a value as a `double`) are not about statistics, but about coding in C.

Comment: @whuber, I understand the code. But, don't understand the logic.

Comment: @whuber, looks like each element was 1st multiplied with their indices and then summed. Then that sum was divided by element sum. Is this weighted sum or what?

Comment: @whuber, supplying some online reference would also be helpful.

Comment: I don't see how online references would be relevant: this is just reverse-engineering code designed to carry out basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have the data

$$x=[0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3]$$
which has mean $\frac{3}{2}$.

One way to compute the mean is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_\alpha x_\alpha$.

Another way is a weighted mean. This means re-arranging the data as a histogram, where $i$ is the value and $j$ is the number of occurrences of $i$ in $x$.

$$
(0,2)\\
(1,4)\\
(2,1)\\
(3,3)
$$

The mean is computed as $\frac{0\times2 + 1\times4 +2 \times 1 + 3\times 3}{2 + 4+ 1+3}=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: kindly, can you provide some reading material?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Pre-Algebra-Concepts-Mastering-Essential-Skills/dp/0966621190/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1536375536&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=algebra&psc=1

Comment: Would the calculation of mean of real numbers follow the same technique?

Comment: If the underlying cdf is *absolutely continuous*, then you'd have $n$ bins each with 1 observation in them. The math works out exactly the same, but why bother?

Comment: Why bother? --- I need to calculate mean of n real numbers.

Comment: So add them up and divide by $n$.

Comment: Why are the solutions different?